# how to hide paypal button code from user?

Tags: php, paypal

how to hide paypal button code from user ?

for example codecanyon.net when i purchase some item i don't see paypal form , how can i do that ?

my user will edit price and currency code

i use code look like this.

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: why not put style on it? style='visibility: hidden' ?

Comment: user will use inspect element to edit.

Comment: then put a php condition that hides it when you're in edit action

Comment: can you show me demo ?

Comment: you had the idea already, it is up to you now on how you will use it if it suites in your code..

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
<input type="text" name="currency_code" value="USD"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
<input type="text" name="amount" value="12.99">

<!-- for submit button -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay now"> 

<!-- for image button -->
<input type="image" src="your button image url" border="0" name="submit" alt="Give here some title">
</form>
```

For currency you should use select box

```
<input type="text" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<select name="currency_code" >
<option value="USD">USD</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use the button tool to create a saved button all the sensitive data is stored in the account and is replaced by a "Button ID". Here's an example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="L7NSNLBNU69AC">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<input type="image" src="your image url" border="0" name="submit" alt="Pay Now">
```